# Python/Selenium - Can only set cookies in the current domain

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping

I am receiving an error which says: `You may only set cookies for the current domain` when trying to perform a login. 
The accompanying message is:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: You may only set cookies for the current domain
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.addCookie (file:///var/folders/28/wvky4dzs7jjfz98kvhdws0qw0000gn/T/tmpirpr_55b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10880)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/28/wvky4dzs7jjfz98kvhdws0qw0000gn/T/tmpirpr_55b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/28/wvky4dzs7jjfz98kvhdws0qw0000gn/T/tmpirpr_55b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/28/wvky4dzs7jjfz98kvhdws0qw0000gn/T/tmpirpr_55b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

I run this segment earlier in the script:

```
for cookie in session.cookies:
driver.add_cookie({
    'name': cookie.name,
    'value': cookie.value,
    'path': '/',
    'domain': cookie.domain
})
```

This transfers the cookies from a `requests.Session()` to a Selenium `webdriver` object so some JavaScript can be executed on the target page.

When I print all these cookies out, all the domains match the target.

How can I get rid of the error? I have absolutely no idea what may be causing it.

Comment: [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is causing it. You have two options. Either visit the site first, and inject the cookies after that, or inject cookies from [code](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#cookies).

Comment: @skandigraun Should I remove cookies from other subdomains of the same site, and then apply them to the `Selenium` object?

Comment: Should not be necessary to remove them (unless they are causing problems to you).

Comment: I solved this problem by rewriting the whole thing using Selenium from the get go. Took my 15 minutes and a have half the code...